# Uhlenbeck's compactness for abelian gauge

Tags: gauge-theory

I am looking for a simpler proof (if possible) for the Uhlenbeck's compactness result (bound on connection up-to gauge from bound on curvature) on an open ball. I know that a proof exists using Hodge-decomposition on closed manifolds (compact without boundary), is there an easier proof for abelian gauge on an open ball (or possibly another version of the result)?